# Trying to create a switch case in python to receive user input for converting values between millimeters/centimeters/meters

Tags: python, function, dictionary

This is what I have come up with so far. No matter what I input, it always run the centimeter function.
I just started python 2 weeks ago after a few months with c++ so I'm still a beginner and I cant seem to find a solution to this.
c++ had switch cases and I tried to replicate it in python using dictionary.
Would appreciate any help I could get :)

```
def centimeter(x):
    print("What do you want to convert ",x," centimeters to?")
    y = str(input("(millimeters/meters):"))
    if y == 'meters':
        print(x," centimeters is", x/100, "meters")
    if y == 'millimeters':
        print(x," centimeters is", x*10, "millimeters")
def millimeters(x):
    print("What do you want to conver",x," millimeters to?")
    y = str(input("(centimeters/meters):"))
    if y == 'centimeters':
        print(x," millimeters is", x/10, "centimeters")
    if y == 'meters':
        print(x," millimeters is",x/1000, "meters")

def choose(measurements):
    converter = {
        1:centimeter(5),
        2:millimeters(5)
    }
    return converter.get(measurements, "1/2:")
ree = input("(1/2): ")
ree_name = choose(ree)
print(ree_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after messing around and doing a  bit more research I finally figured it out.

```
def centimeter():
    x = int(input("Input centimeter: "))
    print("What do you want to convert ",x," centimeters to?")
    y = str(input("(millimeters/meters):"))
    if y == 'meters':
        print(x," centimeters is", x/100, "meters")
    if y == 'millimeters':
        print(x," centimeters is", x*10, "millimeters")
def millimeter():
    x = int(input("Input millimeter: "))
    print("What do you want to convert",x," millimeters to?")
    y = str(input("(centimeters/meters):"))
    if y == 'centimeters':
        print(x," millimeters is", x/10, "centimeters")
    if y == 'meters':
        print(x," millimeters is",x/1000, "meters")
def meter():
    x = int(input("Input meter:"))
    print("What do you want to convert",x," meters to?")
    y = str(input("(millimeter/centimeter):"))
    if y == 'millimeter':
        print(x ," meters is",x*1000,"millimeters")
    if y == 'centimeter':
        print(x, " meter is", x*100,"centimeters")
dispatcher = {
    'centimeter' : centimeter, 'millimeter' : millimeter, 'meter' : meter
}
action = input("(millimeter/centimeter/meter):")
dispatcher[action]()
```

I'm not sure what this part is called but I just experimented with it and it worked. Would be good if anyone can tell me what it is.

```
dispatcher[action]()
```

but yeah, here is the full program if anyone needs it

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you're calling both the `millimeters` and the `centimeters` functions as part of your dict definition:

```
converter = {
    1:centimeter(5),
    2:millimeters(5)
}
```

At this point, both functions are called - first the centimeters one and then the millimeters one. I don't think that's what you meant to do.

What you're probably trying to do is something like:

```
def choose(measurements):
    converter = {
        "1":centimeter,
        "2":millimeters
    }

    func = converter[measurements]
    res = func(5)
    return func
```

Two things to note:

- The keys to the duct should be strings - not integers, as that's what you're getting from the user.
- I'm returning 'func', so it would print the name of the function in the 'main' function. Not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Oh, how do I make it run only what the user inputs?

Comment: I want the user to choose a value they want to input (millimeters,centimeters, meters) and whichever they choose, it will run a function that will let them convert the values to the other 2. So basically user chooses to input meters. User input 5 meters and then the function is called which then lets them choose to whether convert the meter to centimeters or millimeters

Comment: right now im just setting a predetermined value of 5 because I want to fix this first. I'll do the user input later